# How to get Sqlite data as Json using GSON

Tags: android, json, android-sqlite, gson

I'm trying to format my `sqlite` data from all my columns into a `JSONArray`.

My sqlite data example is as follows:

```js
id | name | product |
  
 1 | stev |[{"id":"1","title":"box"}] 

 1 | Lian |[{"id":"2","title":"bag"}] 
 
 1 | beny |[{"id":"3","title":"pen"}]
```

I am saving a `JSONArray` as a string in my database under the column `product`.

I am trying to create a `jsonArray` using `gson library`.

This is what i have tried:

```js
public String composeJSONfromSQLite() {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> offlineList;
        offlineList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM manyofflineCheckouts ";
  
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
              map.put( cursor.getString(0));
              map.put( cursor.getString(1));
              map.put( cursor.getString(2));
              offlineList.add(map);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        database.close();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        //Use GSON to serialize Array List to JSON

        return gson.toJson(offlineList);
    }
```

This however gives me in the format of:

```js
[
 {
     "id":"1",
     "name":"stev",
     "product":"[{"id":"1","title":"box"}]"
 },
 {
     "id":"2",
     "name":"Lian",
     "product":"[{"id":"2","title":"bag"}]"
 }
]
```

This is not the correct `Json` format because of the double quotes surrounding product array `"product":"[{"id":"1","title":"box"}]"`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want the product value to be a JSON array instead of the string you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can solve this is to parse your `product` json string first.

`gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(2), Object[].class)` instead of `cursor.getString(2)` will probably work in your case

Here is demo:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> offlineList = new ArrayList<>();

// here is what i'm taking about
String product = "[{\"id\":\"2\",\"title\":\"bag\"}]";
Object[] productObj = gson.fromJson(product, Object[].class)

HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("product", productObj );
map.put("id", 1);
map.put("name", "stev");
offlineList.add(map);

System.out.println(gson.toJson(offlineList));
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "product": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "bag"
      }
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "name": "stev"
  }
]
```